# SQL- get dates that were used in the WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

We have a ERP that integrates nicely with Crystal Reports.
Now, we can add filters through this application, and it passes these to the report (not as parameters but somehow adds this to the WHERE clause).

The problem is, when filtering dates, we have no way in the report to determine what date range the user selected (as we want to show this date on the report).

Any idea how I can show this through SQL?

I was thinking of using the dual table, and selecting a huge list of dates, then using the MIN and MAX of these dates to determine which was selected. The problem is, I can't join this onto my original query without adding LOTS of rows.

I have this so far:

```
SELECT
  MIN(DTE) MIN_DTE,
  MAX(DTE) MAX_DTE
FROM
(
  SELECT
    TRUNC(SYSDATE)-(5*365) + ROWNUM AS DTE
  FROM
    DUAL
  CONNECT BY
    ROWNUM <= (10*365)
)
WHERE
  DTE >= '12-NOV-07'
  AND DTE <= '12-DEC-07'
```

But the problem is I can't work out how to join that to my original query without upsetting the row cont.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Once a data set is returned to you there is no way to find out what query created that dataset. Why do you not just save the user's selection early on?

Comment: Perhaps you can make the query a stored procedure where the reporting package passes the dates as parameters.  In the stored procedure, it is then trivial to return multiple results including the parameters.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work with stored procedures

Comment: This is an interesting definition of "integrating nicely".

Comment: What does the original query from the application look like?  That might help.

Answer (score 0):

That query returns only one row, so it won't upset the row count at all, unless there is something else going on (like, maybe, the automatic filtering doesn't work in subqueries).

Otherwise, this should work as expected:

```
SELECT q.*, max_min.*
FROM ( ... put your original query here ...) q,
     ( ... put the subquery that returns one row with max & min here ...) max_min
```

That's all to it.